# Is there a way to install Ubuntu stripped down without desktop applications?

Tags: package-management, mono

Just to start off, I know of `lubuntu` but it really doesn't meet what I am looking for.  Basically what I am looking for is the standard Desktop Ubuntu install, but with out all the word processing, multimedia, and games installed.

I have seen posts out about how to get the desktop environment running on Ubuntu server, but they seem complicated, and never seem to equal the standard Desktop install.

So my question is, is there anyway to tell the standard Desktop install not to install all the applications?  Or is there a distro available that leaves all the applications out, and just has the standard desktop look and feel?

What I really want this for is, is for development purposes to run on a VM to do Mono development.

Comment: Why not just install Ubuntu and purge the software you don't want?

Comment: I usually do that. Just thought I would save time and all the unnecessary installs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't such a distribution, but you could install ubuntu-minimal using the alternate installer, or use the alternate installer to customize what you want installed on your system.

After installing ubuntu-minimal you would be left with a command line install, but all you would have to do is run `apt-get install gnome-desktop monodevelop` to get what you are looking for.

Comment: This will do the setup with the Ubuntu theme?

Comment: No, you need to install the ubuntu theme separately (I forgot the name of that package off hand)

Answer (score 3):

The ubuntu minimal cd's are available and can be found here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 1):

Installing the `gnome-core` package should get you a pretty minimal environment.  I would start from a server installation.  You may also need to install `xorg` to get x-windows running and `gdm` to get a login screen.

Comment: Downvoted because as far as I know, installing `gnome-core` would have `xorg` as a dependency.

Comment: @James Gifford: I generally tag all applications installed as depenencies and note packages which are not included as depenencies.  Some versions may include xorg, and all should require a Xserver.  However, I believe I have virtual serves without xorg installed by dependencies and replaced by a VNC server. There are other minimal X environments available which I run on virtual servers.